# Unix - Move folder where containing files match a name

Tags: macos, unix

I was wondering how to move a number of folders to another one, according to the filename of a file inside each of the folders.
I mean, let's assume I have a big amount of folders, each one with a name starting by 'folder*', each one containing 3 files. Specifically one the files contains a string which might be '*-100*', '*-200*' or '*-300*' for example.

I want to move the folders containing the files according to this strings, and put them in a folder called 'string'. For example, to put every folder containing a file which contains the string '*-100*' into the folder 'FOLDER1'I'm trying something like:

**find folder* -name '*100*' -exec mv {} folder* FOLDER1**

but it returns **-bash: /usr/bin/find: Argument list too long.**

How can I pass less arguments to find at every step so I don't get this.

Thank in advance.

Best.

Comment: Its not very clear what you are trying to do, can you give an example of the before and after directory structure you have/want.

Comment: Sorry! The post was a little obscure.
I'm in a path containing a huge set of folders whose names start by folder* (containing each one 3 files, one of which can contain the string '-100', '-200' or '-300') and another one called FOLDER1 (empty). 
I want to move every folder containing a file in its turn containing the string '-100' to FOLDER1, so I can classify the folders depending on the filenames of the containing files.
The problem is that I get an *Argument list too long error* when doing 
*find folder* -name '100' -exec mv {} folder* FOLDER1*

Answer (score 0):

Using your example, and running in the topmost folder containing all the folders, I believe that what you need is this:

`grep -rlw folder* -e "-100" | xargs -I % mv % FOLDER1`

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer!, but I still get an 
*Argument list too long* error when passing the list of all filenames *folder** to grep, the same way it happens with find...